# Python: How do I interact with unicode filenames on Windows? (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, windows, unicode, ntfs

My problem:

> 1. Start with US Windows 10 install
> 2. Create a Japanese filename in Windows explorer
> 3. Open the Python shell, and `os.listdir('.')`
> 4. The listed filename is full of question marks.
> 5. `os.path.exists()` unsurprisingly reports file not found.

NTFS stores the filename as Unicode.  I'm sure if I used the `win32api CreateFile()` series of functions I will get my *Unicode* filename back, however those APIs are too cumbersome (and not portable).  I'd prefer that I get *utf-8* encoded filenames, or the Unicode bytes from the FS directory structure, but in default mode this doesn't seem to happen.

I have tried playing around with `setlocale()` but I haven't stumbled upon the correct arguments to make my program work.  I do not want to (and cannot) install additional code pages onto the Windows machine.  This needs to work with a stock install of Windows.

Please note this has nothing to do with the console.  A repr() shows that the ? chars that end up in the filename listed by `os.listdir('.')` are real question marks and not some display artifact.  I assume they have been added by the API that `listdir()` uses under the hood.

Comment: Do you want to open the file in Python?

Comment: @MelvinAbraham Yes.

Comment: @Keely What do you mean "Unicode filenames"? Windows uses Unicode by default. The filenames *are* Unicode. Strings *are* Unicode. There's nothing difficult, cumbersome or non-portable about them - all Windows programs work with them just fine. Did you try to use *ANSI strings* in your python code with the wrong codepage perhaps?

Comment: @Keely yep, you did `The listed filename is full of question marks.`. Those are *error replacement characters*. It means you used an ANSI string witten using one codepage but your program run using *another* incompatible codepage. You'd have the same problem if you used eg Norgewian characters. Any characters that couldn't be translated were replaced with `?`. The solution is to *not* use codepages.

Comment: +10 to what Melvin said - the console **displays** text using the user's/system's locale. The string may be OK but it will be displayed with replacement characters. You can change the *console's* locale and even switch it to 65536 (UTF8) but that doesn't affect how the program actually works, only how the *console* treats the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be getting `?`s while displaying that filename in the console using `os.listdir()` but you can access that filename without any problems as internally everything is stored in binary. If you are trying to copy the filename and paste it directly in python, it will be interpreted as mere question marks...

If you want to open that file and perform any operations, then, have a look at this...

```
files = os.listdir(".")

# Possible output:
# ["a.txt", "file.py", ..., "??.html"]

filename = files[-1]    # The last file in this case
f = open(filename, 'r')

# Sample file operation

lines = f.readlines()
print(lines)
f.close()
```

**EDIT:**

In Python 2, you need to pass current path as Unicode which could be done using: `os.listdir(u'.')`, where the `.` means current path. This will return the list of filenames in Unicode...

Comment: A simple `chcp 65001` may be enough to display UTF8 text

Comment: Yeah, you can do it if you want to merely _display_ the filename! But if you just want to perform some file operations **programmatically**, then this is one of the ways you could do so.

Comment: That's not an issue.I too did that in command line and later converted into a script for readability. I did everything exactly as described... `os.path.exists(files[-1])` returned `True` in my case (Since, I had that file listed at the last index). By `?`, I mean the Japanese text only which was not being shown as it is. _Seems like you didn't test the code..._

Comment: Python version 3.5.3... in Windows 10 Pro (Build 16299.125)

Comment: Everything works as expected in Python3.  I guess that makes sense.  There are only Unicode strings in Python 3, so when I do `os.listdir()` I get back something describing itself as *str* however that's a python 3 *str* and it carries the unicode chars just fine.  For Python 2 `os.listdir()` returns a Python 2 'str' (i.e. not unicode) object and cannot convey the Unicode chars.  Unfortunately I do need to use Python 2.7 for what I'm doing at the moment, but I will bear this in mind for future projects.

Comment: @Keeely I've got an EDIT for Python 2

Comment: @MelvinAbraham That will just convert byte question marks into Unicode question marks.  (Tested on ActivePython 2.7.14.2717).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173123/discussion-between-keeely-and-melvin-abraham).